# R create a stacked area plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-analysis

I know there are several questions about stacked area plots but I believe my situation is different.
I have data from an income/expense poll and I'd like to show a stacked area plot of the average composition of the expenses by percentile of the population.

So, after summarizing by percentile my data looks like this:

```
Perce    Food    Wear    Car
1        23      15      0
2        25      18      0
..       ..      ..      ..
..       ..      ..      ..
..       ..      ..      ..
99       745     533     300
100      900     800     673
```

It's been tough because the values I want to stack are on different variables.

Any help appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Could you please add a graph similar to the one you are trying to code? Maybe most users (like me) do not get your goal.

Comment: @Alfredo Lozano Could you post the data frame (or a sample of it) you are using: ' `dput(dataframe)`

Comment: You likely just need to reshape the dataset.  [This blog post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-nifty-area-plot-or-a-bootleg-of-a-ggplot-geom/) shows you how to reshape to make a stacked area plot in ggplot2 as well as base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this be what you are looking for? If you make a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question it's easier to help you as I don't know what your actual data looks like.

[image: scale_fill_brewer]

```
# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

data.set <- data.frame(
  Time = c(rep(1, 4),rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4), rep(4, 4)),
  Type = rep(c('Wear', 'Food ', 'Car', 'Pedestrian'), 4),
  Perce = rpois(16, 10)
)

p <- qplot(Time, Perce, data = data.set, fill = Type, geom = "area")
p + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Spectral")
```